# SpeedCrunch is Providing Slow Math Calculations

Tags: debian, math, calculator, speedcrunch

I'm having a performance issue with SpeedCrunch 0.12 in Debian 12:

```
sudo apt install speedcrunch
```

First of all, I love the UI of SpeedCrunch, as a calculator, but currently (for me) it is giving very slow results for even simple math problems like `1 + 1 = 2`.

The tool tip shows the result instantly, but when I press the enter key (to output the result) it takes about 7 seconds to output the calculation.

For just doing one calculation, I can endure the wait, but this 7 second delay (when doing multiple consecutive calculations) after every calculation is unbearable.

Is this only happening for me? If so, what might be causing this?

If this is a bug, are there other calculators, with a similar interface, that anyone can recommend for precise mathematics (until this is fixed)?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, after launching `speedcrunch` from the command line:

[image]

Clearing the history solved the immediate problem:

```
Menu > Edit > Clear History
```

Comment: [Bug 746](https://bitbucket.org/heldercorreia/speedcrunch/issues/746/very-slow-when-history-gets-large)